Proving the projection $f \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^k \langle f, e_i\rangle e_i$ is continuous
Let $f: [0, T] \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\{e_i\}$ a basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I am following a proof where the authors would like to show that the finite projections
$$P_kf := \sum_{i=1}^k \langle f, e_i\rangle e_i,$$
where the inner product is taken in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, belong to $C([0,T]; L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$), i.e. continuous as a function of time taking values in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
To do so they show that
$$\sup_{t \in [0,T]} |\langle f, e_i\rangle| \leq C \tag{1}$$
for some constant $C$ and say it follows that $P_kf \in C([0,T]; L^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$.
Why is the bound (1) on the coefficients enough to show the desired continuity?

I think there is a missing hypothesis, for example I can build a simple counterexample where $f$ is discontinuous and its range is in the span of $e_1$. Maybe one has to assume that $f$ is continuous as well.

@Crostul The full context of this proof can be found in this post. All that is assumed is that $f$ is uniformly bounded in  $L^q(0, T; H^1(\mathbb{R}^n))$ for some $q > 1$ and that the weak partial derivatives $\partial_t f$ are uniformly bounded in $L^p(0, T; H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ for some $p > 1$.
